# Return a namespaced version of a class whose name is provided dynamically

Tags: ruby

I'd like to write a method that would perform my desired output in a scenario like this:

```
class Bar
end

module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

namespace(Bar, Foo)

def namespace(child, parent)
  # return Foo::Bar
end
```

The best I can think of, using ActiveSupport:

```
def namespace(child, parent)
  "#{parent.name}::#{child.name}".constantize
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just write `Foo::Bar` in your program?  Or if you don't want to use ActiveSupport, look at the source code of `constantize` to see how it works.

Comment: Logan, if ActiveSupport is a possibility, suggest you add that as a tag.

Comment: I don't know, what is your need.. But did you think - `Foo.const_get('Bar')` ? It will give you exactly the output, you want.

Comment: @DavidGrayson obviously I can't just write that in my program otherwise I would not be asking this question. And I am fine with using ActiveSupport.

Comment: @ArupRakshit `Foo.const_get` is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @LoganSerman  Not obvious to me, can you give an example?  If you are writing constant literals in your program then just write them with colons between instead.  If you don't have constant literals then what do you have?  If you actually have strings or something, that is important for anyone attempting to answer this question by writing your `namespace` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output as you are looking for, using `Module::const_get` :

```
class Bar
end

module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

def namespace(child, parent)
  parent.const_get(child.name)
end

namespace(Bar, Foo) # => Foo::Bar
```